# Font boosting in android chrome

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, testing

I was very discouraged when I received this bug. On android in the chrome browser (with the system font settings higher than the default), some text blocks grew to fit the increased size of the system font, and some remained the usual size.

After a long and puzzling testing, I came to the conclusion that font boosting is to blame (and this is not a bug but a feature: o)))).

Googling has shown that boosting can be disabled by adding a height or max-height for the parent block. But common sense says that the increase is user friendly and the use of "crutches" will give more problems than it solves.

Testing has shown that, as a rule, blocks with display:inline-block and display:inline-flex do not increase, blocks with absolute positioning also do not increase, and blocks with display: flex behave strangely (they sometimes increase sometimes not).

Questions for connoisseurs (I would be very grateful for an explanation):

1. how can I add the same adequate increase for the above blocks (display: inline-block, display: inline-flex, display: flex, as well as blocks with an absolute)?
2. how can I track how much the system font is increased and is it possible?
3. how can you track which elements have been / have not been subjected to font boosting?

UPD: for myself at the moment I added testing under such conditions, since there are many such cases.

The problem with absolute positioning can still be solved using relative positioning on a mobile phone

The problem with blocks that have display: flex or display: inline-flex is more difficult - i will to use the grid where it should not be used ((

Comment: any updates on that? I tried to add  -moz-text-size-adjust: none;   -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;    text-size-adjust: none; but none of it worked. Have you solved this ''feature''??